# Windows Workflow 4 + ASP.NET Role Manager

Tags: asp.net, workflow-foundation-4

I need to create a simple Windows Workflow 4 Application which requires role based security. the requirement is something like this. user submits a request, then it goes to the manager for approval, he may approve or reject it. if he rejects it comes back to the user for editing and resubmission or user can choose to delete the request. if it is approved, then the request gets completed.

I am using ASP.NET Role based management, but I cant find any simple sample code that demonstrates what I want, I find either very complex WF 4 projects or simple WF 3.5 projects which simply cannot compile using VS2010

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the WCF integration, ie Receive and SendReply activity, this is a standard WCF setup. Lots of examples on the web about how to secure a WCF service using the ASP.NET role provider like [this](http://nayyeri.net/use-asp-net-membership-and-role-providers-in-windows-communication-foundation) one.

Comment: Nope, I am not using WCF and I don't want to

Comment: The WorkflowApplication and WorkflowServiceHost have no security model, it is compltely up to your code then.

Comment: I am just looking for some sample code, I wonder why such a simple example does not exist